# Is it right when I use the method "mux.HandleFunc()"

Tags: go, go-http

I'm a green hand with Go. I have a problem with this code.`

```
package main

import (
   "fmt"
   "log"
   "net/http"
)

func main() {
   mux := http.NewServeMux()
   mux.HandleFunc("/", homePage)
   mux.HandleFunc("/ws", wsEndpoint)
   if err := http.ListenAndServe(":8080", mux); err != nil {
      log.Fatalf("fatal error!")
   }
}

func homePage(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
   fmt.Println("Home Page")
   fmt.Fprint(w, "Home Page")
}

func wsEndpoint(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
   fmt.Println("hello world")
   fmt.Fprint(w, "hello world")
}
```

`
when I curl the url "http://localhost:8080/ws", the goland console prints "Home Page". I cannot understand it.
Any help, thanks.
I use go version of 1.17.8

I have no idea why it excutes "fmt.Println("Home Page")"
Thank you for any help.

Comment: if you open the url in browser  but curl, it will get '/favicon.ico' use `homePage`

Comment: Code seems ok. Start by using Go 1.19 and _not_ using an IDE.

Comment: Thank you Para, I use curl command in Centos and then it prints what I expect.